# getCall d oes not discern ... when the model function is wrapped in another function

Tags: r

If I wrap a model-fitting function, as an example the glmer from the lme4 package, in another function and allow a ... argument it is not discerened by getCall. Is this a bug?

```
library(lme4)
x = rnorm(100)
beta0 = 1
beta1 = 2
fact = factor(rep(1:4, each = 25))
y = beta0 + beta1 * x + rep(rnorm(4), each = 25) + rnorm(100)
dat <- data.frame("y" = y, "x" = x, "fact" = fact)
f <- function(data, formula, ...) { 
  lmer(formula, data, ...)
}
mod1 <- f(data = dat, formula = formula(y ~ x + (1|fact)), 
 control = lmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead"))

mod2 <- lmer(data = dat, formula = y ~ x + (1|fact), 
  control = lmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead"))
getCall(mod1)
getCall(mod2)
```

Comment: Are you saying this code returns an error for you? It seems to work fine for me. What exactly is the problem here? Tested with `lme4_1.1-21`

Comment: No but the Control Argument Does Not Show

Comment: And that's important for some reason? This question is just about getting a prettier output? If you are trying to build the exact same function call, then you will need to do something like `f <- function(data, formula, ...) { cc <- match.call(); cc[[1]] <- quote(lmer); eval.parent(cc)}`.

Comment: If you pass the Output of f to another function that uses getCall this can lead to bugs